# Multiselect property of Datagridview now selecting full row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a window form that has a datagridview. In this datagridview i am adding two columns dynamically as shown in below code.My problem is that when i click on these added columns ,Multiselect property is not selecting full row but when i click on first column of grid it selected full row.

```
 if (gvlayoutload.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn comboBoxColumnRInfo =
                          new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.Name = "RowInfo";
                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.HeaderText = "";
                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.DataPropertyName = "RowInfo";
                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.ReadOnly = true;
                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.Width = 25;
                    comboBoxColumnRInfo.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    //comboBoxColumnRInfo.Frozen = true;
                    this.gvlayoutload.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumnRInfo);

                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn comboBoxColumn =
                          new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                    comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Row #";
                    comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "RowNo";
                    comboBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;
                    comboBoxColumn.Width = 45;
                    comboBoxColumn.FillWeight = 45;
                    //comboBoxColumn.Frozen = true;
                    FRColumn col = new FRColumn();
                    col.Name = comboBoxColumn.HeaderText;
                    col.Type = 1;
                    col.Variable1 = variable1;
                    col.Variable2 = variable2;
                    col.Percent = Percent;
                    col.Rowno = Rowno;
                    col.Headersize = 8;
                    col.Bodysize = 8;
                    col.HeaderAlign = 0;
                    col.BodyAlign = 0;
                    lstcolumn.Add(col);
                    this.gvlayoutload.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
```

When i click on RowInfo column or Row # column Multiselect property not selected full row.I have set multiselect property to true and multiselection mode is fullrowmode.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property indicates how the cells of the DataGridView can be selected. The default value is `RowHeaderSelect`. The behavior of each mode is described in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link.

The first column in the `DataGridView` contains the row headers. If you select any cell in this column it will select the full row when the `SelectionMode` is `RowHeaderSelect` or `FullRowSelect`.

If you want to select multiple rows then set the `DataGridView.MultiSelect = true`.

You can also hide that column by setting `DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false`.